# Conditional Probability of a random variable. Quick question.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to find $P(X<3\mid X>2)$, and I know $P(X>2)=\frac34$ and $P(X<3)=\frac12$ from the integration of pdf.

Is correct to say: $P(X<3\mid X>2)= \displaystyle \frac{\frac12}{\frac34}$?

Comment: On top we want $\Pr((X\gt 2)\cap (X\lt 3))$. That is not $1/2$.

Comment: We have $P(X<3|X>2) = \frac{P(2<X<3)}{P(X>2)} = \frac{1-P(X<2)-P(X>3)}{P(X>2)} = \frac{1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{1}{3}$.